# with wrong pam_environment unable to login

Tags: login, pam

I made some mistakes in my ~/.pam_environment file; the changes caused a login failure.

I cannot log in to my system. I only have one super account. I tried to press ctrl-alt-f1 to enter into full screen login mode, however I still couldn't login.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you know exactly what changes you made?  Was it to only this file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try booting into “single user mode” or “recovery mode” in order to fix your problem. As I'm not Using vanilla Ubuntu installations *that* often, I'm not sure how the latest version of the recovery mode looks like, whether its shell option will ask you for a password, and if it does, whether that passwort check uses pam. So you'll have to give it a try.

If that doesn't work, as a last resort you could append `init=/bin/bash` to your boot command line in grub. That will dump you into a shell very early during boot, so many services will not be available, but it won't display a login prompt either, so it should enable you to fix your pam setup unless that is on a partition which isn't mounted by that time. You'll probably have to remount your root fs writable before doing any changes: `mount / -o remount,rw`.

Comment: Booting from a liveCD and repairing manually is also an option, if recovery mode doesn't work. Mounting should be done as in this answer.